# Android application to learn English for small kids

Tags: android, educational, children

Please recommend me an android application that teaches English for small kids (max 5 years). It is okay if it's not free. My kid can't read, so this tool should **teach through images**.

I have tried availing [Kids Learn English with Busuu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.busuu.kids.en), but my kid simply passed through the screens without learning and threw it away after ten minutes.

My child is a Polish speaker, but this is not important for kids. They are generally learning from images, sounds and animations/movies.

Should be ads free and without in-payment. Should be optimized for tablets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research I will recommend to myself :)

### Picture books from [Oceanhouse Media, Inc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Oceanhouse+Media,+Inc.) with  professional audio narration

- [Just Me and My Mom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oceanhouse_media.booklcjustmeandmymom_app&hl=en)
- [When I Get Bigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oceanhouse_media.booklcwhenigetbigger_app&hl=en)
- [All By Myself - Little Critter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oceanhouse_media.booklcallbymyself_app&hl=en)

and more.

This books contains **auto play** mode — plays like a movie, automatically reading and turning pages. Great for younger children.

---

### Picture books from [Frima Studio Inc.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Frima+Studio+Inc.) with audio narration

- [CosmoCamp: Picnic Problems](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frimastudio.android.CosmoCamp) and other books

> Frima Studio, Canada’s largest independent game developer, teamed up with child development specialists from a renowned Canadian university to offer parents meaningful, skill-building, yet fun, child-oriented apps.
>   Recommended ages: 2-3, 4-5

---

No spam, adverts and in-payments, safe for young children and nice looking.

Answer (score 6):

[**Duolingo**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duolingo)

This one has been voted as  "**Best of the Best**" 2013
The UI is great and it uses gamification so your kid will enjoy it. **No ads**. No price. You can try the [**web version here**](http://www.duolingo.com/).

[Cartoon- Free English](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pitzunda.cartonix.enfree&feature=also_installed)

**//update- This contains huge ads**
This one here helps learners learn new words through the use of a method called word cards. They use pictures to illustrate meaning.

Comment: My kid **can't read and write** :)

Answer (score 0):

Memrise - it is much better for my eight years old daughter than Duolingo, very easy to play with.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.memrise.android.memrisecompanion

Cons: It has in-payment :(